# How to call a function in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, cfc, application.cfc, application.cfm

I a test.cfc I have created a component in Application.cfc using

```
<cffunction name="onApplicationStart">
   <cfset application.api = {tst= createObject( "component", "com.Test" )} />   
   <cfreturn true />
</cffunction>
```

Now how do I call a method in Test.cfc in my cfm file ?

Comment: `application.api.tst.doSomething()`

Comment: Im doing it like this. <cfinvoke method="application.api.tst.doSomething()" returnVariable="list" /> It doesn't seem to work

Comment: You'd need <cfinvoke component="#application.api.tst#" method="doSomething" returnVariable="list" />

Comment: you do realise you are putting your object into a struct right? that application.api is a struct and not the actual object?

Comment: Then your question should be of the form "I am trying to call a function like this <code> but I am getting the error <error>"!

Comment: Actually I need to put cfc in application scope and call a method in it in my cfm file. Is the above code a correct way to do it ?

Comment: http://www.learncfinaweek.com/

Answer (score 2):

This code

```
<cffunction name="onApplicationStart">
   <cfset application.api = {tst= createObject( "component", "com.Test" )} />   
   <cfreturn true />
</cffunction>
```

defines the variable `application.api.tst`. You want define a variable by calling a method in this object (CFC).

You can define the variable `list` in two ways:

```
<cfinvoke component="#application.api.tst#" method="doSomething" returnVariable="list" />
```

as Sean describes or by using a simple `CFSET`

```
<cfset list = application.api.tst.doSomething() />
```

The value of `list` is based on whatever was returned by the function `doSomething`, which is a public function inside the component `com.Test` that exists in the application variable.

You should be able to output of `CFDUMP` the value of `list` at this point. If the variable does not have the value you expected, then you need to verify what the function `doSomething` is returning.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation for a beginner like me